# How to increase the height of combo box in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down list in asp.net. I want to increase its height. please suggest, how to icrease it.

Comment: I will suggest that you should should show us some code.

Comment: Why you want to increase the height ?

Comment: i think you can try out using css

Answer (score 0):

There is a height property on the drop down list.

```
myDropDown.Height = 200;
```

BTW:  There is pleny of information around on how to do it:

http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/forums/asp.net-dropdownlist-item-height/p/3151/31235.aspx

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=419074

http://forums.asp.net/t/1300753.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

If setting the height property is not helping you,
One way of achieving this by increasing the font of the `dropdown` as it gets set based on the height of its contents.

Or you could set it via css (not sure will work in all browsers)

Please edit to describe your current scenario with some code

Answer (score -1):

Set the `Height` property of the [control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)